# how to replace a text in a file in assembly using DOS instruction

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16

NASM ASSEMBLER
Assume we have created a text file using a notepad  with the following text:

```
      “Of all the languages I've studied, Assembly is   
        my favorite.”
```

Suppose we want to change "favorite“ to  “fun-fun"  by inserting the word “fun-fun" in place of “favorite."  How do we do it - without disturbing or rewriting those first 47 bytes before "my"?

I thought reading every byte first would be a start..

```
mov AH, 3F ; AH=3F=read
mov BX, in_handle
mov CX,60
Int 21H
```

Then lost???

Comment: I see you trying to read the file, but I don't see you open it.  Did you do that first?  As for writing, it's a question of [writing](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah40) at the correct position.  How do you set the position?  Well, you can read everything up to (but not including) "favorite", or you can use [lseek](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah42).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov BX, in_handle
> ```

If you're using NASM then the above will load the **address** of the *in_handle* variable in `BX`. That's not what you need! You want the **contents** of this variable.

```
mov bx, [in_handle]
```

---

> ```
> mov AH, 3F ; AH=3F=read
> mov BX, in_handle
> mov CX,60
> Int 21H
> ```

The function number that you move to `AH` is the hexadecimal number 3Fh. You must write the suffix "h" or the prefix "0x".
For consistency with `int 21h`, you should choose "h"

---

> without disturbing or **rewriting** those first 47 bytes before "my"?

If rewriting if not an option then you must use the DOS.MoveFilepointer function 42h.

```
mov     dx, 47        ; Fileoffset in CX:DX is 47
xor     cx, cx
mov     bx, [in_handle]
mov     ax, 4200h     ; AH=function 42h AL=offset from start of file
int     21h           ; DX:AX CF
jc      SomeError
mov     dx, Buffer    ; Buffer at DS:DX
mov     cx, 9999      ; Everything till EndOfFile
mov     bx, [in_handle]
mov     ah, 3Fh       ; DOS.ReadFile
int     21h           ; -> AX CF
jc      SomeError
```

Here you modify the contents of the buffer so it reads "fun-fun". Please notice that it's 1 character less than "favorite"! That's what makes it necesary to re-write till the EndOfFile. You don't want to leave a gap in the text.

To update the file you re-position the file pointer just like above followed by using the DOS.WriteFile function 40h from the same buffer but with a smaller count in `CX`.

Why `mov cx, 9999` (only while reading)?

Notepad will have attached bytes 13 (carriage return) and 10 (linefeed) to the end of the line! Maybe even byte 26 (end of file).
Don't worry, DOS will only read what is available and very importantly report about the amount in the `AX` register. Consult the API/manual.

Comment: Not sure about "you must use."  DOS files can be opened in read/write mode, and reading updates the file pointer.  So I'd expect that it's possible to read up to the point where you want to write, then issue a write.  Don't know that that's any better than seeking.  I'm just not comfortable with "must."

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Reading the file up to a certain point as a means to position the file pointer is an inefficient way of doing it. In this mini file that the OP uses, it would not matter since that file fits completely in a single DOS file buffer. But as a general advice it's just not good enough.

Comment: The other option for consistency is to use `0x3f` and `0x21`, of course.  But most DOS documentation uses `h` suffixes so it's probably a good suggestion to use that, since NASM supports both.